# Finding Value among multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe. In its one column there are single values and in its coresponding column there are subset of values. I have to check whether B is present in A Values_2 column, then whether C is present in B Values_2 column, then check whether D is present in C Values_2 column and so on.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame() 

df1['Values_1'] = ['A','B' ,'C', 'D'] 
df1['Values_2'] = [[F, G, H , B, Z], [C, Q, R, T, U], [C, Q, R, T, 
U], [C, Q, R, T, U], [C, Q, R, T, U]] 

Values_1                              Values_2              Output
1 A                                   [F, G, H , B, Z]       B
2 B                                   [C, Q, R, T, U]        C
3 C                                   [P, W, D, F, L]        D
4 D                                   [Y, E, M, N, V]        E
5 E                                   [S, X, I, K, J]        Nan
```

Comment: Put some effort into (1.) having the correct syntax in your question. Add quotes for strings. (2.) Make sure your dataframe example matches up with your setup code. You've got `[C, Q, R, T, U]` 4 times in your setup code but the data in `Values_2` has distinct rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare sets by intersection and for first match value is used `next` with `iter`, so possible add defaut value `NaN` if no match:

```
s = set(df1['Values_1'])
df1['Output'] = df1['Values_2'].map(lambda x: next(iter(list(set(x) & s)), np.nan))
```

EDIT:

If need teste shifted values per rows:

```
df1['Output'] = (df1.assign(a = df1['Values_1'].shift(-1, fill_value=''))
                    .apply(lambda x: x['a'] if x['a'] in x['Values_2'] else '', axis=1))
print (df1) 
  Values_1         Values_2 Output
0        A  [F, G, H, B, Z]      B
1        B  [C, Q, R, T, U]      C
2        C  [C, Q, R, T, U]       
3        D  [C, Q, D, T, U]       
4        E  [W, Q, R, T, U]
```

Comment: its giving me correct output jezrael for this input. but let me modify my dataframe little bit

Comment: @Bilal - Sure, also please dont forget check commnet under question.

Comment: @jezrael I think OP wants to do a _shifted_ `Values_1 in Values_2` check - so the 2nd row's `Value_1` is checked against the 1st row's `Value_2`. (Already worked out how to do it but so can you :-) and OP should edit their question as needed.)

Comment: Kindly open this link for my edited question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66452631/finding-correct-person-among-multiple-person-names

Comment: @Bilal - So it means is necessary test in previous group? rows from group 3 are tested in groups 2 rows, rows from 2 are tested in 1 group?

Comment: Yes it is necessary.