# Finding correct person among multiple person names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe. In its one column there are single values and in its coresponding column there are subset of values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

Index   Values_1                            Values_2                                          
1  Muhammad bin Bashr bin al-Farafsa   Isma'il bin Abi Khalid al-
                                       Ahmsi [11418], Hisham bin 
                                       'Urwa [11065], Yahya bin 
                                       Sa'id bin Hiyan [11404]

1  Muhammad bin Bkar bin Bilal         Sa'id bin Basahyr al-Azdi 
                                       [20710], Sa'id bin 'Abdul
                                       'Aziz al-Tanuqi [20638]

1  Muhammad bin Bashar Bindar          Mua'dh bin Hisham bin Aby 
                                       [20287], Yahya bin Sa'id bin 
                                       Farroukh al-Qatan [20031]

2  Yahya bin Sa'id bin Farroukh al-Qatan  Y'aqub bin Ibrahim bin Kathir 
                                          [30400], Sh'uba[198]

2  Yahya bin Sa'd ibn Abi Waqqas          Sa'd ibn Abi Waqqas [9]

3  Hamza bin al-Mughira bin Shu'ba        al-Mughira ibn Shu'ba 
                                          [166] 

3  Shu'ba                                 Yahya bin Sa'id al khudri
```

I have to check whether Values_1 at index no 2 is present in any of the Values_2 present at index no 1.First groupby values by index For example, check whether Yahya bin Sa'id bin Farroukh al-Qatan is present in any of the Values_2 present at index 1

```
Output
Index   Values_1                        Values_2

 1      Muhammad bin Bashar Bindar      Mua'dh bin Hisham bin Aby 
                                        [20287], Yahya bin Sa'id 
                                        bin Farroukh al-Qatan 
                                        [20031]

2      Yahya bin Sa'id bin Farroukh al-Qatan Y'aqub bin Ibrahim bin Kathir
                                             [30400], Sh'uba[198]

3      Shu'ba                                Yahya bin Sa'id al_Khudri
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert values to list and subtract index by 1 for match by next group
s = df.groupby(level=0)['Values_1'].agg(list)
s.index = s.index - 1
print (s)
Index
0    [Muhammad bin Bashr bin al-Farafsa, Muhammad b...
1    [Yahya bin Sa'id bin Farroukh al-Qatan, Yahya ...
2            [Hamza bin al-Mughira bin Shu'ba, Shu'ba]
Name: Values_1, dtype: object
```

---

```
#replace NaN to emty list
df['test'] = df.index.map(s).map(lambda x: [] if isinstance(x, float) else x)

#test if at least one value match from list from previous group
f = lambda x: any([y in x['Values_2'] for y in x['test']])
mask = df.apply(f, axis=1)

#filter by mask and remove helper column
df = df[mask].drop('test',axis=1)
print (df)
                         Values_1  \
Index                               
1      Muhammad bin Bashar Bindar   

                                                Values_2  
Index                                                     
1      Mua'dh bin Hisham bin Aby [20287], Yahya bin S...
```

Comment: jezrael its giving me empty dataframe not the desired ouput

Comment: @Bilal - hmmm, it means data not match

Comment: @Bilal - I thinjk problem is in data - e.g. in sample data not match Index=2, also Index=3 but it is expected, because cannot see Index=4 data

Comment: sorry i didn't get u sir. What are u trying to say?

Comment: @Bilal - If check data in question, why is ouput form `Index=2` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229448/discussion-between-bilal-and-jezrael).